# Rewrite rule not working with big query parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite the URL

http://oldptl.mycompany.com/Apps/Learning.aspx?pm_actstr=study&destUrl=https%3a%2f%2fwyn%2eplateau%2ecom%2flearning%2fuser%2fdeeplink%5fredirect%2ejsp%3flinkId%3dITEM%5fDETAILS%26componentID%3dSOHO%5fWOW%5f2015%5f06%26componentTypeID%3dILT%26revisionDate%3d1430164500000%26fromSF%3dY&company=mycompany

to

http://newptl.mycompany.com/MyPtl/Enter%20the%20Learning%20Zone?pm_actstr=study&destUrl=https%3a%2f%2fwyn%2eplateau%2ecom%2flearning%2fuser%2fdeeplink%5fredirect%2ejsp%3flinkId%3dITEM%5fDETAILS%26componentID%3dSOHO%5fWOW%5f2015%5f06%26componentTypeID%3dILT%26revisionDate%3d1430164500000%26fromSF%3dY&company=mycompany

But the below rewrite rule is not working

RewriteRule ^/Apps/Learning.aspx?pm_actstr=study&destUrl=$ http://newptl.mycompany.com/MyPtl/Enter%20the%20Learning%20Zone?pm_actstr=study&destUrl=

Rewrite rule is not getting invoked. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below rewrite rule did the trick

RewriteRule ^/Apps/Learning.aspx$ http://newptl.mycompany.com/MyPtl/Enter%20the%20Learning%20Zone?